# YII2: How to add ICON in the gridview header

Tags: gridview, yii2-advanced-app

How to add an icon beside the header of a GRIDVIEW?

something like this.

```
[
   'attribute' => 'address',
   'format'=>'raw',
   'label'=>'<i class=\"fa fa-map\"><\i>test',
],
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set 'encodeLabel' property of DataColumn to false

```
        [
            'attribute' => 'address',
            'label' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">' ,
            'encodeLabel' => false,
        ],
```